# Tools for 3D animations, models, skeletons and other animation techniques

Tags: 11.10, animations

I am looking for apps in Ubuntu that I can work to create 3D animations, models and other similar stuff. Similar for example to Maya and 3D Studio in Windows.

With which apps can I count on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**[Blender](http://www.blender.org/)**

Install

```
sudo apt-get install blender
```

[Docs and videos How to's](http://www.blender.org/education-help/)

[image]

**[Wings 3D](http://www.wings3d.com/)**

Install

```
sudo apt-get install wings3d
```

[Documentation](http://www.wings3d.com/wiki.php?title=Documentation)

[image]

**[K-3D](http://www.k-3d.org/)**

Install

```
sudo apt-get install k3d
```

[K-3D Mug Tutorial](http://www.k-3d.org/video)

[image]

Comment: Well I had forgotten about Blender lol. The other one I did not know about. Thanks again Achu.

Answer (score 0):

[Blender](http://www.blender.org/) is absolutely the best in my opinion. Great tool working superb under Linux, many tutorials, and years of usage. And add to that build in game-engine. I am using it and i am very satisfied.